# After Updating ADT 23, SDK path miss from preference

Tags: android, sdk, adt, android-5.0-lollipop

After Updating the ADT 23 getting the error for annotation tried too much appreciated solutions but can't able to solved it.

**Then after new problem arise that the SDK path not Found in Preference when tried to set Path again There is no enable ok button.**

NOTE: Using ADT bunble eclipse "Not specific eclipse version JUNO or etc". 
      Using Ubuntu OS 12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got The solution and now project is build successfully.

1.) Delete the Android SDK tool package(Updated package with Latest ADT) from Android SDK manager.

2.) I have old bundle .zip file which is i am using,
    Extract it and copy the **tool** folder from there and past it in current sdk.

Comment: yes absolutely right.just before I solved it like these.